# Configure maven registry in .m2

Tags: java, maven, gitlab, dependency-management

I would like to use the gitlab package registry globally.

My situation is as follows:

1. I' working on several maven projects for which I use a nexus server for my packages.
2. In my team, we would like to get rid of this nexus server because of maintenance effort in some migrations.
3. I recently found the gitlab package registry tool which works well so far when we want to push our packages.
4. Now we have the want to configure a settings.xml in our .m2 folder so that the dependencies are getting fetched from gitlab ci globally.

Is there please a way to do that? So far we just found the possibility with applying the parameter -s to the mvn command line which does not fit to our processes.

A template of a settings.xml would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you read https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/maven_repository/, there are all the information you need.

Comment: Yes!
I tried with the following code:

~~~
<settings>
  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>gitlab-maven</id>
      <configuration>
        <httpHeaders>
          <property>
            <name>Private-Token</name>
            <value>REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN</value>
          </property>
        </httpHeaders>
      </configuration>
    </server>
  </servers>
</settings>
~~~

But it acts as I haven't configured anything.

Comment: This part is useful for configuring credentials of a repository in order to push artifact. What you also need is a `<repository>` configuration with the URL of the repository. Read the whole page ;)